# When would you use $* instead of $@ in Bourne shells?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, bourne-shell

In Bourne shell and its offshoots like Bash, I believe the only difference between `$*` and `$@` is that `$@` expands in double quotes so that each argument ends up as a single word even if it contained embedded whitespace while `$*` doesn't.

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in $*; do echo $i; done
for i in $@; do echo $i; done
for i in "$*"; do echo $i; done
for i in "$@"; do echo $i; done
```

...when invoked with `'1 2' 3` as arguments, the first two output `1`, `2`, then `3`, the thrid outputs `1 2 3`, but the fourth correctly outputs `1 2` then `3`.

Is `$*` just redundant, and if it is, why is it used in so many scripts?

Comment: Haven't you just identified a case where they do different things? How can they be redundant then?

Comment: You correctly looped over the single word you provided to loop over. There's not much reason to loop over a single item, of course.